# Using sed to reorder mixed up entries in columns

Tags: sed, data-cleaning

Edit: Added more data around, to match the real case thank @Beta

I have data like below -

```
<vector node='1' label='a'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='2' label='b'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='3' label='c'>
(("some data here"))

<vector label='d' node='4'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='5' label='e'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='6' label='f'>
(("some data here"))

<vector label='g' node='7'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='8' label='h'>
(("some data here"))
```

This is to be sorted using sed/awk etc. I did try and use sed exchange (x) command, but apparently one can only exchange lines and not patterns.

Edit: I want it to look like this

```
<vector node='1' label='a'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='2' label='b'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='3' label='c'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='4' label='d'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='5' label='e'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='6' label='f'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='7' label='g'>
(("some data here"))

<vector node='8' label='h'>
(("some data here"))
```

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: Thanks, have added that part now @Beta

Comment: `sed 's/\(l.*\) \(n.*\)/\2 \1/'`

Comment: @Beta check now, thanks for the edits

Comment: @Beta it moves the ">" with it, but let me see if I can do something

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -E "s/(label='[^']*') (node='[^']*')/\2 \1/" myfile
```

Comment: Hi, I can't verify if it works anymore. Can't access the data now. Thanks for the answer!